# How does node.js next() middleware function work without arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Middleware functions have a signature `function (req, res, next)`, but in Express the `next()` call does not contain arguments. How is this so? See the following example from the
[sample documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

It certainly could be the case that a wrapping function is created that under-the-hood binds the arguments, allowing for a call with no additional parameters, but the documentation seems to indicate that the `next` parameter is called as-is, which does not make sense.

Comment: What argument should be provided (eg. why does no-arguments not seem valid)? "Calling this function invokes the next middleware function in the app." -- seems legit to me.

Comment: A middleware function like `myLogger` has a signature of `function (req, res, next)`. If `next` is the next middleware function in the chain, it should also have this signature; however, it is called with no arguments. In the above example I would expect the `next` argument of myLogger to be the function created in the second parameter of the `app.get` call, so that the full chain is that the request comes in, executes myLogger, and then executes the Hello World function, but I do not see how myLogger forwards `req, res`.

Comment: Anyway, this behavior could be implemented to closures, adding state to the function-object itself, or spring-boarding exceptions. None of which are particularly exciting and the specific implementation can be seen in the source..

Comment: The 'next' function simply ensures the next pipeline component is called with the same req/res as the first. The req/res objects are shared the entire request pipeline. There is absolutely *no requirement / expectation* that next is the actual 'app.get' function in the pipeline (and indeed, it is not, and thus there is no mandate to pass arguments) - the `next` function merely *ensures* the next pipeline function is called, isolating one step from the next.

Comment: If the implementation is a closure, then that is a perfectly acceptable state of affairs and I agree with what you are saying about it being an implementation detail. I just wish the documentation said this to avoid the confusion.
The trouble is it states explicitly that myLogger is a middleware function and that `next` is a middleware function, but actually `next` is a closure that wraps the middleware.

Comment: The [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) says "*Notice the call above to next(). Calling this function **invokes the next middleware function** in the app.* The next() function is not a part of the Node.js or Express API, but is the third argument that is passed to the middleware function. The next() function could be named anything, but by convention it is always named “next”." - Not exactly how to read more or less into that; it's the API provided that "*invokes* the next [..] function". There is no mention of next *being* the next middleware function..

Answer (score 1):

The docs describe the third argument, conventionally named `next`, as

> Callback argument to the middleware function, called "next" by convention.

You can think of it similar to the conventional node.js callback-style argument provided to most async functions (without promises). When your middleware function is done doing its sync or async work, it should call `next` to indicate to the express router that it is done executing. This argument could be called `done` or `callback`, as we often see in other node.js libraries and examples, but is called `next` to provide a hint to the developer that the middleware chain will continue execution (other middleware may be called after this one).